# C# Console, Connect 4 Game

Tags: c#, beginner, game, console, connect-four

this is my second post here, and the second project I made. I wanted to know, how to improve my code of connect-4 made in c# for console.

```
using System;

namespace Connect_4
{
    class Program
    {
        // computer's board, that computer checks if someone wins
        static string[] BoardColumn1 = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
        static string[] BoardColumn2 = { "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l" };
        static string[] BoardColumn3 = { "m", "n", "p", "p", "q", "r" };
        static string[] BoardColumn4 = { "t", "u", "v", "w", "i", "y" };
        static string[] BoardColumn5 = { "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
        static string[] BoardColumn6 = { "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "(" };
        static string[] BoardColumn7 = { ")", "-", "_ ", "+", "=", "}" };

        // what the user sees
        static string[] UserBoardColumn1 = { " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " };
        static string[] UserBoardColumn2 = { " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " };
        static string[] UserBoardColumn3 = { " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " };
        static string[] UserBoardColumn4 = { " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " };
        static string[] UserBoardColumn5 = { " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " };
        static string[] UserBoardColumn6 = { " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " };
        static string[] UserBoardColumn7 = { " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " };

        static int turn = 0;
        static bool playing = true;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Intro();

            while (playing) //stops the game once someone wins
            {
                Board(); 

                if (turn % 2 == 0) // tells whose turn it is
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1's turn");
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 2's turn");
                }

                int UserChoice;
                Console.WriteLine("Type the number you want your token to go in or type restart to restart"); //takes user input
                bool IsChoiceInt = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out UserChoice);

                if (IsChoiceInt) //checks if is correct input
                {
                    if (UserChoice == 1) // checks if someone wants to put the token in 1 and puts it there
                    {
                        int EmptyLocation = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn1, " ");
                        if (EmptyLocation == -1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Stop trying to steal other people's places");
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        }
                        else if (turn % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            turn++;
                            BoardColumn1[EmptyLocation] = "o";
                            UserBoardColumn1[EmptyLocation] = "o";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            turn++;
                            BoardColumn1[EmptyLocation] = "x";
                            UserBoardColumn1[EmptyLocation] = "x";
                        }
                        Board();
                        VerticalWinCondition();
                        HorizontalWinCondition();
                        DiagonalWin();
                        IsTieGame();
                    }
                    else if (UserChoice == 2) // checks if someone wants to put the token in 2 and puts it there
                    {
                        int EmptyLocation = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn2, " ");
                        if (EmptyLocation == -1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Stop trying to steal other people's places");
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        }
                        else if (turn % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            turn++;
                            BoardColumn2[EmptyLocation] = "o";
                            UserBoardColumn2[EmptyLocation] = "o";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            turn++;
                            BoardColumn2[EmptyLocation] = "x";
                            UserBoardColumn2[EmptyLocation] = "x";
                        }
                        Board();
                        VerticalWinCondition();
                        HorizontalWinCondition();
                        DiagonalWin();
                        IsTieGame();
                    }
                    else if (UserChoice == 3) // checks if someone wants to put the token in 3 and puts it there
                    {
                        int EmptyLocation = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn3, " ");
                        if (EmptyLocation == -1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Stop trying to steal other people's places");
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        }
                        else if (turn % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            turn++;
                            BoardColumn3[EmptyLocation] = "o";
                            UserBoardColumn3[EmptyLocation] = "o";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            turn++;
                            BoardColumn3[EmptyLocation] = "x";
                            UserBoardColumn3[EmptyLocation] = "x";
                        }
                        Board();
                        VerticalWinCondition();
                        HorizontalWinCondition();
                        DiagonalWin();
                        IsTieGame();
                    }
                    else if (UserChoice == 4) // checks if someone wants to put the token in 4 and puts it there
                    {
                        int EmptyLocation = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn4, " ");
                        if (EmptyLocation == -1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Stop trying to steal other people's places");
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        }
                        else if (turn % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            turn++;
                            BoardColumn4[EmptyLocation] = "o";
                            UserBoardColumn4[EmptyLocation] = "o";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            turn++;
                            BoardColumn4[EmptyLocation] = "x";
                            UserBoardColumn4[EmptyLocation] = "x";
                        }
                        Board();
                        VerticalWinCondition();
                        HorizontalWinCondition();
                        DiagonalWin();
                        IsTieGame();
                    }
                    else if (UserChoice == 5) // checks if someone wants to put the token in 5 and puts it there
                    {
                        int EmptyLocation = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn5, " ");
                        if (EmptyLocation == -1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Stop trying to steal other people's places");
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        }
                        else if (turn % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            turn++;
                            BoardColumn5[EmptyLocation] = "o";
                            UserBoardColumn5[EmptyLocation] = "o";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            turn++;
                            BoardColumn5[EmptyLocation] = "x";
                            UserBoardColumn5[EmptyLocation] = "x";
                        }
                        Board();
                        VerticalWinCondition();
                        HorizontalWinCondition();
                        DiagonalWin();
                        IsTieGame();
                    }
                    else if (UserChoice == 6) // checks if someone wants to put the token in 6 and puts it there
                    {
                        int EmptyLocation = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn6, " ");
                        if (EmptyLocation == -1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Stop trying to steal other people's places");
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        }
                        else if (turn % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            turn++;
                            BoardColumn6[EmptyLocation] = "o";
                            UserBoardColumn6[EmptyLocation] = "o";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            turn++;
                            BoardColumn6[EmptyLocation] = "x";
                            UserBoardColumn6[EmptyLocation] = "x";
                        }
                        Board();
                        VerticalWinCondition();
                        HorizontalWinCondition();
                        DiagonalWin();
                        IsTieGame();
                    }
                    else if (UserChoice == 7)// checks if someone wants to put the token in 7 and put it there
                    {
                        int EmptyLocation = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn7, " ");
                        if (EmptyLocation == -1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Stop trying to steal other people's places");
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        }
                        else if (turn % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            turn++;
                            BoardColumn7[EmptyLocation] = "o";
                            UserBoardColumn7[EmptyLocation] = "o";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            turn++;
                            BoardColumn7[EmptyLocation] = "x";
                            UserBoardColumn7[EmptyLocation] = "x";
                        }
                        Board();
                        VerticalWinCondition();
                        HorizontalWinCondition();
                        DiagonalWin();
                        IsTieGame();
                    }
                    else if (UserChoice > 7 || UserChoice < 0) //error check
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please input a valid number, the valid numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7");
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }
                }
                else //error check
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please input a valid number, the valid numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }

            }
        }

        static void Board() //makes the board
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("  1   2   3   4   5   6   7");
            Console.WriteLine($"| {UserBoardColumn1[5]} | {UserBoardColumn2[5]} | {UserBoardColumn3[5]} | {UserBoardColumn4[5]} | {UserBoardColumn5[5]} | {UserBoardColumn6[5]} | {UserBoardColumn7[5]} |");
            Console.WriteLine($"| {UserBoardColumn1[4]} | {UserBoardColumn2[4]} | {UserBoardColumn3[4]} | {UserBoardColumn4[4]} | {UserBoardColumn5[4]} | {UserBoardColumn6[4]} | {UserBoardColumn7[4]} |");
            Console.WriteLine($"| {UserBoardColumn1[3]} | {UserBoardColumn2[3]} | {UserBoardColumn3[3]} | {UserBoardColumn4[3]} | {UserBoardColumn5[3]} | {UserBoardColumn6[3]} | {UserBoardColumn7[3]} |");
            Console.WriteLine($"| {UserBoardColumn1[2]} | {UserBoardColumn2[2]} | {UserBoardColumn3[2]} | {UserBoardColumn4[2]} | {UserBoardColumn5[2]} | {UserBoardColumn6[2]} | {UserBoardColumn7[2]} |");
            Console.WriteLine($"| {UserBoardColumn1[1]} | {UserBoardColumn2[1]} | {UserBoardColumn3[1]} | {UserBoardColumn4[1]} | {UserBoardColumn5[1]} | {UserBoardColumn6[1]} | {UserBoardColumn7[1]} |");
            Console.WriteLine($"| {UserBoardColumn1[0]} | {UserBoardColumn2[0]} | {UserBoardColumn3[0]} | {UserBoardColumn4[0]} | {UserBoardColumn5[0]} | {UserBoardColumn6[0]} | {UserBoardColumn7[0]} |");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
        }
        static void VerticalWinCondition() //checks if someone won vertially
        {
            if (BoardColumn1[0] == BoardColumn1[1] && BoardColumn1[0] == BoardColumn1[2] && BoardColumn1[0] == BoardColumn1[3] || BoardColumn1[1] == BoardColumn1[2] && BoardColumn1[1] == BoardColumn1[3] && BoardColumn1[1] == BoardColumn1[4] || BoardColumn1[2] == BoardColumn1[3] && BoardColumn1[2] == BoardColumn1[4] && BoardColumn1[2] == BoardColumn1[5])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn2[0] == BoardColumn2[1] && BoardColumn2[0] == BoardColumn2[2] && BoardColumn2[0] == BoardColumn2[3] || BoardColumn2[1] == BoardColumn2[2] && BoardColumn2[1] == BoardColumn2[3] && BoardColumn2[1] == BoardColumn2[4] || BoardColumn2[2] == BoardColumn2[3] && BoardColumn2[2] == BoardColumn2[4] && BoardColumn2[2] == BoardColumn2[5])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn3[0] == BoardColumn3[1] && BoardColumn3[1] == BoardColumn3[2] && BoardColumn3[2] == BoardColumn3[3] || BoardColumn3[1] == BoardColumn3[2] && BoardColumn3[1] == BoardColumn3[3] && BoardColumn3[1] == BoardColumn3[4] || BoardColumn3[2] == BoardColumn3[3] && BoardColumn3[2] == BoardColumn3[4] && BoardColumn3[2] == BoardColumn3[5])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn4[0] == BoardColumn4[1] && BoardColumn4[1] == BoardColumn4[2] && BoardColumn4[0] == BoardColumn4[3] || BoardColumn4[1] == BoardColumn4[2] && BoardColumn4[1] == BoardColumn4[3] && BoardColumn4[1] == BoardColumn4[4] || BoardColumn4[2] == BoardColumn4[3] && BoardColumn4[2] == BoardColumn4[4] && BoardColumn4[2] == BoardColumn4[5])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn5[0] == BoardColumn5[1] && BoardColumn5[1] == BoardColumn5[2] && BoardColumn5[2] == BoardColumn5[3] || BoardColumn5[1] == BoardColumn5[2] && BoardColumn5[1] == BoardColumn5[3] && BoardColumn5[1] == BoardColumn5[4] || BoardColumn5[2] == BoardColumn5[3] && BoardColumn5[2] == BoardColumn5[4] && BoardColumn5[2] == BoardColumn5[5])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn6[0] == BoardColumn6[1] && BoardColumn6[1] == BoardColumn6[2] && BoardColumn6[2] == BoardColumn6[3] || BoardColumn6[1] == BoardColumn6[2] && BoardColumn6[1] == BoardColumn6[3] && BoardColumn6[1] == BoardColumn6[4] || BoardColumn6[2] == BoardColumn6[3] && BoardColumn6[2] == BoardColumn6[4] && BoardColumn6[2] == BoardColumn6[5])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn7[0] == BoardColumn7[1] && BoardColumn7[1] == BoardColumn7[2] && BoardColumn7[2] == BoardColumn7[3] || BoardColumn7[1] == BoardColumn7[2] && BoardColumn7[1] == BoardColumn7[3] && BoardColumn7[1] == BoardColumn7[4] || BoardColumn7[2] == BoardColumn7[3] && BoardColumn7[2] == BoardColumn7[4] && BoardColumn7[2] == BoardColumn7[5])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
        }
        static void HorizontalWinCondition() // checks if soemone won horizontally
        {
            if (BoardColumn1[0] == BoardColumn2[0] && BoardColumn1[0] == BoardColumn3[0] && BoardColumn1[0] == BoardColumn4[0])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn1[1] == BoardColumn2[1] && BoardColumn1[1] == BoardColumn3[1] && BoardColumn1[1] == BoardColumn4[1])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn1[2] == BoardColumn2[2] && BoardColumn1[2] == BoardColumn3[2] && BoardColumn1[2] == BoardColumn4[2])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn1[3] == BoardColumn2[3] && BoardColumn1[3] == BoardColumn3[3] && BoardColumn1[3] == BoardColumn4[3])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn1[4] == BoardColumn2[4] && BoardColumn1[4] == BoardColumn3[4] && BoardColumn1[4] == BoardColumn4[4])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn1[5] == BoardColumn2[5] && BoardColumn1[5] == BoardColumn3[5] && BoardColumn1[5] == BoardColumn4[5])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
        }
        static void DiagonalWin() //checks if a player won diagonally
        {
            if (BoardColumn1[0] == BoardColumn2[1] && BoardColumn1[0] == BoardColumn3[2] && BoardColumn1[0] == BoardColumn4[3] || BoardColumn1[1] == BoardColumn2[2] && BoardColumn1[1] == BoardColumn3[3] && BoardColumn1[1] == BoardColumn4[4] || BoardColumn1[2] == BoardColumn2[3] && BoardColumn1[2] == BoardColumn3[4] && BoardColumn1[2] == BoardColumn4[5])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn1[5] == BoardColumn2[4] && BoardColumn1[5] == BoardColumn3[3] && BoardColumn1[5] == BoardColumn4[2] || BoardColumn1[4] == BoardColumn2[3] && BoardColumn1[4] == BoardColumn3[2] && BoardColumn1[4] == BoardColumn4[1] || BoardColumn1[3] == BoardColumn2[2] && BoardColumn1[3] == BoardColumn3[1] && BoardColumn1[3] == BoardColumn4[0])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }

            else if (BoardColumn2[0] == BoardColumn3[1] && BoardColumn2[0] == BoardColumn4[2] && BoardColumn2[0] == BoardColumn5[3] || BoardColumn2[1] == BoardColumn3[2] && BoardColumn2[1] == BoardColumn4[3] && BoardColumn2[1] == BoardColumn5[4] || BoardColumn2[2] == BoardColumn3[3] && BoardColumn4[2] == BoardColumn2[4] && BoardColumn2[2] == BoardColumn5[5])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn2[5] == BoardColumn3[4] && BoardColumn2[5] == BoardColumn4[3] && BoardColumn2[5] == BoardColumn5[2] || BoardColumn2[4] == BoardColumn3[3] && BoardColumn2[4] == BoardColumn4[2] && BoardColumn2[4] == BoardColumn5[1] || BoardColumn2[3] == BoardColumn3[2] && BoardColumn4[3] == BoardColumn2[1] && BoardColumn2[3] == BoardColumn5[0])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }

            else if (BoardColumn3[0] == BoardColumn4[1] && BoardColumn3[0] == BoardColumn5[2] && BoardColumn3[0] == BoardColumn6[3] || BoardColumn3[1] == BoardColumn4[2] && BoardColumn3[1] == BoardColumn5[3] && BoardColumn3[1] == BoardColumn6[4] || BoardColumn3[2] == BoardColumn4[3] && BoardColumn3[2] == BoardColumn5[4] && BoardColumn3[2] == BoardColumn6[5])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn3[5] == BoardColumn4[4] && BoardColumn3[5] == BoardColumn5[3] && BoardColumn3[5] == BoardColumn6[2] || BoardColumn3[4] == BoardColumn4[3] && BoardColumn3[4] == BoardColumn5[2] && BoardColumn3[4] == BoardColumn6[1] || BoardColumn3[3] == BoardColumn4[2] && BoardColumn3[3] == BoardColumn5[1] && BoardColumn3[3] == BoardColumn6[0])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }

            else if (BoardColumn4[0] == BoardColumn5[1] && BoardColumn4[0] == BoardColumn6[2] && BoardColumn4[0] == BoardColumn7[3] || BoardColumn4[1] == BoardColumn5[2] && BoardColumn4[1] == BoardColumn6[3] && BoardColumn4[1] == BoardColumn7[4] || BoardColumn4[2] == BoardColumn5[3] && BoardColumn4[2] == BoardColumn6[4] && BoardColumn4[2] == BoardColumn7[5])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
            else if (BoardColumn4[5] == BoardColumn5[4] && BoardColumn4[5] == BoardColumn6[3] && BoardColumn4[5] == BoardColumn7[2] || BoardColumn4[4] == BoardColumn5[3] && BoardColumn4[4] == BoardColumn6[2] && BoardColumn4[4] == BoardColumn7[1] || BoardColumn4[3] == BoardColumn5[2] && BoardColumn4[3] == BoardColumn6[1] && BoardColumn4[3] == BoardColumn7[0])
            {
                playing = false;
                Winner();
            }
        }

        static void IsTieGame() //checks if game is tie
        {
            int TieCheker1 = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn1, " ");
            int TieCheker2 = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn2, " ");
            int TieCheker3 = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn3, " ");
            int TieCheker4 = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn4, " ");
            int TieCheker5 = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn5, " ");
            int TieCheker6 = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn6, " ");
            int TieCheker7 = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn7, " ");

            if (TieCheker1 == -1 && TieCheker2 == -1 && TieCheker3 == -1 && TieCheker4 == -1 && TieCheker5 == -1 && TieCheker6 == -1 && TieCheker7 == -1)
            {
                playing = false;
                Tie();
            }
        }

        static void Intro() //Intro
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to");
            Console.WriteLine(@"  ______   ______   .__   __. .__   __.  _______   ______ .___________.    _  _    ");
            Console.WriteLine(@" /      | /  __  \  |  \ |  | |  \ |  | |   ____| /      ||           |   | || |   ");
            Console.WriteLine(@"|  ,----'|  |  |  | |   \|  | |   \|  | |  |__   |  ,----'`---|  |----`   | || |_  ");
            Console.WriteLine(@"|  |     |  |  |  | |  . `  | |  . `  | |   __|  |  |         |  |        |__   _| ");
            Console.WriteLine(@"|  `----.|  `--'  | |  |\   | |  |\   | |  |____ |  `----.    |  |           | |   ");
            Console.WriteLine(@" \______| \______/  |__| \__| |__| \__| |_______| \______|    |__|           |_|   ");
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress a Key to begin");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            Rules();
        }
        static void Rules() //Rules
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How to Play:");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Choose who plays first. Player 1 will be 'o' and Player 2 will be 'x'");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Player's will alternate taking turns on putting their token in the board. You will put your token in the board by typing in the number at the top of the column you wish to put it in.  ");
            Console.WriteLine("3. The first player to get 4 tokens in a row wins. The four in a row can be horizontal, vertical or diagonal");
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress a Key to begin");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void Winner() //message when player wins game
        {
            if (turn % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congrats on winning player 2");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congrats on winning player 1");
            }
        }
        static void Tie() //message when tie game
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The game is a tie");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't want to be rude but with 200+ lines `Main` function it does seem like that you haven't learned anything from the previous review.

Comment: Confirm that previous review is mostly applicable to this code.

Answer (score 1):

### Single Level of Abstraction

Currently your Main method contains the call to `Intro()` and then the game
loop. It would be easier to understand the code from a high level if the game
loop were also in its own method. The Main method would then look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Intro();
    StartGameLoop();
}
```

Thus both method calls are on the same level of abstraction, and to look into
the details (e. g. loops, variables etc.) one can look into those methods.

Seeing that `Rules()` is called by `Intro()`, we have another example of multiple
abstraction levels being mixed within the same method, which makes it more
difficult to understand the code. If the rules are considered part of the intro,
you could put all those `Console.WriteLine()` statements from `Rules()` directly
into `Intro()`, but that would make the method very long. Instead, I would prefer
to call `Intro()` and then `Rules()` separately, turning the body of the Main
method into this:

```
Intro();
Rules();
StartGameLoop();
```

### Useless comments

Most if not all of the comments in this piece of code are unnecessary, but the
best examples of completely useless comments are `Rules() //Rules`
and `Intro() //Intro`. They add no information, but clutter the code.
Also comments like `IsTieGame() //checks if game is tie` are not helpful,
since the name already explains well what the method does (or at least as well
as the comment).

In other cases, we can make the comments obsolete (and should then also remove
them) by improving names of variables or methods. For example we can replace this ...

```
HorizontalWinCondition() // checks if soemone won horizontally
```

... with this ...

```
CheckIfSomeoneWonHorizontally()
```

Often the comment itself can be a good indicator of what the method name should
have been.

Similarly, we can replace this ...

```
Winner() //message when player wins game
```

... with this ...

```
AnnounceWinner()
```

### Conventions

Most programming languages have established conventions for how code should
be formatted and how names should look. Variable names should start
with a lowercase letter, so `UserChoice` should be `userChoice`, and similar
occurrences in the code. I recommend looking up the C# coding conventions from
Microsoft, which can be considered the "official" conventions and a de-facto
industry standard.

### Naming

Method names should concisely but accurately describe what the method does, and
should generally be verbs. In some cases we can use a noun phrase as a method
name if the method returns something rather than executing a command.

The names like `Intro()`, `Rules()` and `Board()` are not descriptive. Clearer
would be e. g. `PrintIntro()`, `DisplayRules()`, `DrawBoard()` or similar.

Some names are even misleading. `IsTieGame()` only checks whether the board is
full. The consequence could be that the game is a tie, if at the point where
the board is full no player has won yet, but it is an assumption that is not
covered by this method. I would rename `IsTieGame()` to `IsBoardFull()`, return
a boolean (`true` if the board is full, otherwise `false`), and call `Tie()`
outside of this method only if the board is full *and* no player has won yet.

### Error checking

The variable `IsChoiceInt` represents whether the player's input could
successfully be parsed as an integer, but the error message indicates that only
the numbers in the range 1..7 are valid. Because the range of the number is not
checked, another check is necessary, duplicating the exact same error message.
It would be better to check all expected preconditions of the input at the start,
and to rename `IsChoiceInt` to `isInputValid`.

### Structure

The code contains a lot of duplication. That's problematic for multiple reasons,
but mostly because when reading the code one has to read a lot more code than
necessary to get the same amount of information. Also, if you make a mistake
somewhere and have to fix it, you have to fix it in many places, which is not
only tedious to do, but also bears the risk of missing one occurrence, thus
still having a mistake in the code somewhere.

The biggest duplication is this block, which occurs 7 times:

```
else if (UserChoice == 6) // checks if someone wants to put the token in 6 and puts it there
{
    int EmptyLocation = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn6, " ");
    if (EmptyLocation == -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stop trying to steal other people's places");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
    else if (turn % 2 == 0)
    {
        turn++;
        BoardColumn6[EmptyLocation] = "o";
        UserBoardColumn6[EmptyLocation] = "o";
    }
    else
    {
        turn++;
        BoardColumn6[EmptyLocation] = "x";
        UserBoardColumn6[EmptyLocation] = "x";
    }
    Board();
    VerticalWinCondition();
    HorizontalWinCondition();
    DiagonalWin();
    IsTieGame();
}
```

All 7 occurrences of this block of code are exactly the same *except* which
column is being used (in the example above it is `BoardColumn6`). So why not
select the column once, and then run this code for that chosen column? This could
look roughly like this:

```
string[] chosenBoardColumn;
string[] chosenUserBoardColumn;
if (UserChoice == 1)
{
    chosenBoardColumn = BoardColumn1;
    chosenUserBoardColumn = UserBoardColumn1;
}
else if (UserChoice == 2)
{
    chosenBoardColumn = BoardColumn2;
    chosenUserBoardColumn = UserBoardColumn2;
}
// etc.

int EmptyLocation = Array.IndexOf(UserBoardColumn6, " ");
if (EmptyLocation == -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Stop trying to steal other people's places");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
else if (turn % 2 == 0)
{
    turn++;
    chosenBoardColumn[EmptyLocation] = "o";
    chosenUserBoardColumn[EmptyLocation] = "o";
}
else
{
    turn++;
    chosenBoardColumn[EmptyLocation] = "x";
    chosenUserBoardColumn[EmptyLocation] = "x";
}
Board();
VerticalWinCondition();
HorizontalWinCondition();
DiagonalWin();
IsTieGame();
```

This is still not great, but a good first step, and still similar to the original
code structure, minus the duplication.

Next we can extract some methods for selecting the columns and for handling the
user input. Let's name them `ChooseBoardColumn(int userChoice)`,
`ChooseUserBoardColumn(int userChoice)`, and
`PlayTurn(string[] chosenBoardColumn, string[] chosenUserBoardColumn)`.

Thus that long `if (IsChoiceInt)` block can be reduced to this:

```
if (IsChoiceInt)
{
    string[] chosenBoardColumn = ChooseBoardColumn(UserChoice);
    string[] chosenUserBoardColumn = ChooseUserBoardColumn(UserChoice);

    PlayTurn(chosenBoardColumn, chosenUserBoardColumn);
    DrawBoard();
    CheckVerticalWinCondition();
    CheckHorizontalWinCondition();
    CheckDiagonalWin();
    CheckTieGame();
}
```

### Logic

Checking every case of 4 in a row individually is very inefficient and error
prone. I recommend trying to find a way to use loops to check the win conditions.
By using a 2-dimensional array instead of 7 individual array variables, this
will additionally become much easier to do.

Comment: A linearised 2D array is most convenient for checking wins - for the 4 different orientations, we just use a different stride (1, width, width-1 and width+1).